# Generating JSON Array Object from flat data

Tags: javascript, angular

Please let me know how to generate the below output from flat data

### flat data

```
exco, business,  product

10   Europe    shampooA
10   USA       shampooB
20.  India.    watch
30   china.    fans
```

### output

```
\[{"exco":10, Businesses\[{"business":"Europe",Products:\[{"product":"shampooA"}\]}\]},
{"business":"USA","Products":\[{"product":"shampooB"}\]}}\]},
{ "exco":20,Businesses\[{"business":"Europe",Products:\[{"product":"watch"}\]}\]},
{ "exco":30,Businesses\[{"business":"china",Products:\[{"product":"fans"}\]}\]}
\]
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose You have flat Data like below

```
const flatData = [
    { exco: 10, business: "Europe", product: "shampooA" },
    { exco: 10, business: "USA", product: "shampooB" },
    { exco: 20, business: "India", product: "watch" },
    { exco: 30, business: "China", product: "fans" },
];
```

Then You can convert the object to your desired format like below. It iterates through each item in the flatData and checks if there is an existing entry in the output array with the same "exco" value. If there is an existing entry, it adds the new business and product information to the existing entry. If there is no existing entry, it creates a new entry in the output array.

```
const output = flatData.reduce((result, item) => {
const existingItem = result.find((x) => x.exco === item.exco);

if (existingItem) {
    existingItem.Businesses.push({ business: item.business, Products: [{ product: item.product }] });
} else {
    result.push({
        exco: item.exco,
        Businesses: [{ business: item.business, Products: [{ product: item.product }] }],
    });
}

return result;
}, []);

console.log(output);
console.log(JSON.stringify(output)); // if you want json string
```

Comment: thanks a lot but same change in it, some time business may have multiple products